# RSpec - FactoryGirl sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm brand new to factory girl and pretty new to RSpec in general. I'm trying to set a sign in for the user as a factory. I thought this would be a good intro to Factories. I think I set the factory right but now I need to know how to implement it in the actual test. Ill show the test I've written thus far and maybe I can get some guidance through.

Here is factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do

    email "cam@example.com"
    password "password"

  end
end
```

here is the feature test:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Send a message" do
  scenario "Staff can send a message" do
    visit "/"

    group = Group.create!(name: "Group A")
    user = User.create!(email: "staff@example.com", password: "password")
    fill_in "Email", with: "staff@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: "password"
    click_button "Sign in"

    person = Person.create!(groups: [group], phone_number: "+161655555555")
    message = Message.create(body: "Test Message", group_ids: [group.id])
    fill_in "Enter a Message:", with: "Test Message"
    check "message_group_#{group.id}"
    click_button "Send Message"

    expect(page).to have_content("Messages on their way!")
    expect(page).to_not have_content("Body can't be blank")
    expect(page).to_not have_content("Group ids can't be blank")
  end
end
```

I basically want to make a factory out of this chunk. That way I will not have to repeat this code over and over again right?

```
group = Group.create!(name: "Group A")
user = User.create!(email: "staff@example.com", password: "password")
fill_in "Email", with: "staff@example.com"
fill_in "Password", with: "password"
click_button "Sign in"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factories are meant to create data, not execute a series of steps. What you want is a function to do this for you.

Something akin to this:

```
def sign_in
  visit "/"

  group = Group.create!(name: "Group A")
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
end
```

In your test

```
scenario "Staff can send a message" do
  sign_in

  # Rest of code
end
```

Or

```
before(:each) { sign_in }

scenario "Staff can send a message" do
  # Rest  of code
end
```

You can define this function in this file, in your `spec_helper` / `rails_helper` or within a file in `spec/support/`